# Weirdest combobox exception: GeneratorPosition '-1,1' "passed to Remove does not have Offset equal to 0". Parameter name: position

Tags: c#, silverlight

I honestly have no idea what's going on here, I can only find this error mentioned in a few specific places around the whole of the internet. I'm using Silverlight4. I have a combobox that is bound to an observable collection. The observable collection has two things in it. If I try and set the combobox's selectedindex to 0, it works fine, but if I try and set it to one, I get the exception:

"GeneratorPosition '-1,1' "passed to Remove does not have Offset equal to 0". Parameter name: position"

..Any thoughts at all? The only really useful reference I found to this was http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightgen/thread/e6e07c42-4d64-4973-965d-c4b6dd32cfd9 and it seems to indicate that it's a problem native to Silverlight.

Comment: For those occasional googlers that come across this, I don't recall exactly how I fixed this, but it wound up being something silly like setting the combobox's itemssource to null, setting a new observablecollection equal to the old one, and then assigning the new one to the combobox's itemssource.

Comment: This error is a source (hidden behind TargetInvocationException) for me. I'm binding ComboBox to List<> and after I reset List to new and bind SelectedItem I get this error

Comment: @katit It seems like Silverlight is slowly getting less and less functional as it's migrating from extending support to long term life support.

Comment: I don't think it's getting less functional. Maybe no fixes, but definitely not getting worse :) By the way, I got it fixed. Basically when setting source and selected value (doesn't matter via binding or code) you want to re-set it every time you do change to underlying list. And when you already set source - don't change contents of list. Now it works and code looks ok, just need to keep it in mind..

Comment: @katit I love silverlight, I think it's a great platform for making web applications and I'm disappointed it looks to be discontinued. I've stopped working with it though because in the last year I started running into more edge case browser incompatibilities, including a particular nasty one involving cookies. As for your bug, did you try binding to an `ObservableCollection` instead? I don't know if that makes a difference, but I always used that class.

Comment: I continue using Silverlight. I don't get into any troubles yet. Will give HTML5 couple more years :) As far as ObservableCollection - I found them somewhat heavy and my UI is pretty complex, I try to use those for more complex list structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those occasional googlers that come across this, I don't recall exactly how I fixed this, but it wound up being something silly like setting the combobox's `ItemsSource` to `null`, setting a new `ObservableCollection` equal to the old one, and then assigning the new one to the combobox's `ItemsSource`.

Really I think this comes down to Silverlight being kind of buggy. I'm curious why it's actually happening if someone wants to go and use the reflector, but the above should help all the same.